# Android on TV vs Chromecast built-in (official Android TV)

Tags: android-tv, chromecast, smart-tv

Recently, I have seen TVs announced as official Android TV (Android 11)  with Chromecast built-in. But these TVs are hardly usable without setting up a Google account.

However, I am aware of TVs with Android 9 completely usable by adding a Google account, that includes a media player/web browser, access to external storage, and even a specific store for apps.

I can't find a comparative but at least I found some differences and big limitations:

- The lack of a preinstalled web browser
- A limited and restricted Play, no Chrome or Firefox
- Not possible to install APKs from external storage
- Some apps installed from APKs are not recognized by the default launcher (requires a sideload launcher)

Is there information about all the limitations introduced by Google?
Is it possible to move to standard Android/Play?
Would future updates of Android TV remove potential installed APKs?

Answer (score 3):

So a few notes, and **TDLR**:

1. Devices with Google Play Services/Google Play Store are expected to follow the [Android Compatibility Program](https://source.android.com/docs/compatibility/overview) and specifically the [Android Compatibility Definition Document (CDD)](https://source.android.com/docs/compatibility/cdd) for the version a particular device is released with.
2. As you can see the television section of the [CDD for Android 9](https://source.android.com/docs/compatibility/9/android-9-cdd#2_3_television_requirements) has fewer requirements that the [CDD for Android 13](https://source.android.com/docs/compatibility/13/android-13-cdd#23_television_requirements), but more importantly for Android 13 there exists a [CDD for Android 13 - TV Android - Developer Compatibility section](https://source.android.com/docs/compatibility/13/android-13-cdd#236_developer_tools_and_options_compatibility) which means the `adb` must be available.

**Your post in detail**

So lets go through your points:

> - the lack of a preinstalled webbrowser

I'm not aware of a requirement in the CDD for a preinstalled web browser. The fact that Chrome comes with Google Play Services is a contract issue between Google and Device Manufacturer (OEM/ODM).

> - a limited and restricted Play, no Chrome or Firefox

At a guess those apps don't support Android TV as specified in the [Developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start#tv-activity) which calls out using `android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER` in the Android Manifest file. These values are baked into the app at compile time.

> - some apps installed from apks are not recognized by default launcher (requires a sideload launcher)

Enforcement of the above rule as you have seen appears to be circumvented by alternate launchers.

> - Not possible install apks from external storage

So in the CDD, [Section 4 for Application Packaging Compatibility](https://source.android.com/docs/compatibility/9/android-9-cdd#4_application_packaging_compatibility)

> **SHOULD** provide a user affordance to grant/revoke the permission to install apps from unknown sources per application, but **MAY** choose to implement this as a no-op and return RESULT_CANCELED for startActivityForResult(), if the device implementation does not want to allow users to have this choice. However, even in such cases, they **SHOULD** indicate to the user why there is no such choice presented.

The requirement from installing for `unknown sources` is **optional** by the manufacturer.

The saving grace is that `adb` / developer mode appears to be hard requirement, so developers trying to debug their app on a particular device have the ability to do so.

As for your questions:

> Is there information about all the limitations introduced by Google?

See prior referenced documentation about what is mandated for a device launching with a specific version of Android.

> Is it possible to move to standard Android/Play?

Unlikely and will probably require root access.

> Would future updates of AndroidTV remove potential installed apks?

No for apps installed via `adb` as those would be used by developers for testing/debugging. If a published app via the Google Play Store is found to be malicious, Google has been known to remove those apps. Individual app publishers may set API toggles within their app, i.e. a streaming service is turning off support for older versions of their app.

Comment: Thanks Morrison, your reply contains very useful information. And I 'll pay attention to the changelog of the android upgrades.